# Get possible paths

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a simple data structure showing nodes in a directed graph:

```
{
    'node1': [('V1', 'R1')],
    'node2': [('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R3')],
    'node3': [('R2', 'R4'), ('R2', 'R5'), ('R3', 'R4'), ('R3', 'R5')],
    'node4': [('R4', 'Z1')],
    'node5': [('R5', 'Z1')]
}
```

I'd like to get all possible (directed) paths from V1 to Z. For example, a path might be:

```
[
    ('V1', 'R1'),
    ('R1', 'R2'),
    ('R2', 'R4'),
    ('R4', 'Z1')
]
```

Yet I'm having trouble with what seems like a basic algorithm, which I believe involves recursion.

```
for node, connections in nodes.items():
    for connection in connections:
```

I started with something like the above but I think that's the wrong approach. What would be the suggested way to do this, without using something like `itertools` ?

Comment: What is the size of the largest graph this should work on? (recursion might be a bad idea for huge graphs) Will there (possibly) be loops in your directed graph?

Comment: @Grismar very small. It's a toy graph, not for an actual application.

Comment: Also, is there special meaning to the grouping in "nodes"? Because it appears the tuples are really denoting edges between nodes like `V1` and `R1` and something like `node1` is just an arbitrary grouping?

Comment: @Grismar no -- just a convenience for being able to read and see the different nodes (and draw it) a bit more easily.

Comment: I think the naming 'nodes' may actually be a bit confusing, but at least it shouldn't affect the answer than. It's confusing because what's called a 'node' in your example data isn't actually (in graph theory) a 'node'.

Comment: @Grismar -- you're right. I confused the two, it should be something like "connections" as it just gives a list of edges at a certain 'junction point'. Node would be something like `V1` which I've confused in the above. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the tuples in the data structure are the edges and the values in the tuples are the graph's nodes, it's possible to reorganise the data in a way that makes the algorithm simpler:

```
graph = [edge for es in source.values() for edge in es]
```

Since there might be loops in the graph, we need to keep track of nodes that have already been visited. A recursive function with that in mind, finding all paths from a start node to and end node, give the graph as a list of edges from node to node:

```
def find_path(start, end, edges, visited=None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = []
    for n1, n2, in edges:
        if n1 == start:
            if n2 == end:
                yield [n1, n2]
            elif n2 not in visited:
                for continuation in find_path(n2, end, edges, visited + [n1]):
                    yield [n1] + continuation
```

The whole thing:

```
source = {
    'node1': [('V1', 'R1')],
    'node2': [('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R3')],
    'node3': [('R2', 'R4'), ('R2', 'R5'), ('R3', 'R4'), ('R3', 'R5')],
    'node4': [('R4', 'Z1')],
    'node5': [('R5', 'Z1')]
}

graph = [edge for es in source.values() for edge in es]


def find_path(start, end, edges, visited=None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = []
    for n1, n2, in edges:
        if n1 == start:
            if n2 == end:
                yield [n1, n2]
            elif n2 not in visited:
                for continuation in find_path(n2, end, edges, visited + [n1]):
                    yield [n1] + continuation


print(list(find_path('V1', 'Z1', graph)))
```

Output:

```
[['V1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R4', 'Z1'], ['V1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R5', 'Z1'], ['V1', 'R1', 'R3', 'R4', 'Z1'], ['V1', 'R1', 'R3', 'R5', 'Z1']]
```

Note that the result is cast to a list because the function is a generator, it yields solutions one at a time. The call to `list()` collects all the results in a single output.

Comment: thanks again for this answer. After studying this a bit and practicing recursion, I came up with my own solution below which is a bit 'more basic' and friendly for me to understand (i.e., it doesn't use yield). Would you take a look and let me know if it looks like I'm on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
data = {'node1': [('V1', 'R1')], 'node2': [('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R3')], 'node3': [('R2', 'R4'), ('R2', 'R5'), ('R3', 'R4'), ('R3', 'R5')], 'node4': [('R4', 'Z1')], 'node5': [('R5', 'Z1')]}
new_data = [i for b in data.values() for i in b]
def lookup(start, end, seen=[], c = []):
   _r = [(a, b) for a, b in new_data if a == start and a not in seen]
   for a, b in _r:
      if b == end:
         yield c+[(a, b)]
      else:
         yield from lookup(b, end, seen=seen+[start], c=c+[(a, b)])

print(list(lookup('V1', 'Z1')))
```

Output:

```
[
  [('V1', 'R1'), 
   ('R1', 'R2'), 
   ('R2', 'R4'), 
   ('R4', 'Z1')], 
  [('V1', 'R1'),  
   ('R1', 'R2'), 
   ('R2', 'R5'), 
   ('R5', 'Z1')], 
  [('V1', 'R1'), 
   ('R1', 'R3'), 
   ('R3', 'R4'), 
   ('R4', 'Z1')], 
  [('V1', 'R1'), 
   ('R1', 'R3'), 
   ('R3', 'R5'), 
   ('R5', 'Z1')]
]
```

Comment: thanks, that's very nifty. Could you please explain your code a bit. For example, why you need to define `new_data`, and what `c` is?

Comment: @David542 Your original input data contained `node` keys which (from my view) have no real bearing on the path finding task. `new_data` stores all the tuple pairs from `data`. `c` is a running list of all the collected paths, `yield`ed back when the desired end node is found.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is much less elegant and more verbose than the other two solutions, but here is an example implementation expanding the various functions out:

```
def flatten_list(l, out=None):
    """
    Flatten to get a list of all edges:

    in:  [[('V1', 'R1')], [('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R3')]
    out: [('V1', 'R1'), ('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R3')]
    """
    if out is None: out=[]
    for li in l:
        if not isinstance(li, list):
            out.append(li)
        else:
            flatten_list(li, out)
    return out


def get_connected_nodes_from(list_of_edges, from_node):
    """
    Given an input node (string), and list of edges (tuple),
    Return a list of all nodes (list of strings) connected to the input node.
    Note: this is a directed graph. That is, we are only grabbing descendants
          and not all (undirected) edges.

    in:  from_node='R1', list_of_edges=[('V1', 'R1'), ('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R3')]
    out: ['R2', 'R3']
    """
    out = []
    for edge in list_of_edges:
        if edge[0] == from_node:
            out.append(edge[1])
        elif from_node == edge[0]:
            out.append(edge[0])
    return out


def get_all_paths(list_of_edges, node=None, current_path=None, all_paths=None):
    """
    Given a list of edges, this will return all directed paths from start to finish.
    """
    # "Initialize" things on the first time through
    if all_paths is None: all_paths = []; node = list_of_edges[0][0]; current_path = [node,]
    node_descendants = get_connected_nodes_from(list_of_edges, node) 
    if len(node_descendants) == 0:
        all_paths.append(current_path) # append the path when it is a leaf with no descendants
    else:
        [get_all_paths(list_of_edges, node, current_path + [node,], all_paths) for node in node_descendants]
    return all_paths
```

And using it:

```
>>> graph = {
    'node1': [('V1', 'R1')],
    'node2': [('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R3')],
    'node3': [('R2', 'R4'), ('R2', 'R5'), ('R3', 'R4'), ('R3', 'R5')],
    'node4': [('R4', 'Z1')],
    'node5': [('R5', 'Z1')],
}
>>> list_of_edges = flatten_list(graph.values())
>>> print (['-->'.join(path) for path in get_all_paths(list_of_edges)])
# ['V1-->R1-->R2-->R4-->Z1', 'V1-->R1-->R2-->R5-->Z1', 'V1-->R1-->R3-->R4-->Z1', 'V1-->R1-->R3-->R5-->Z1']
```